# How do I customize the subject line length for COMMIT_EDITMSG in VS Code?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I use VS Code for my `core.editor` when using Git Bash on Windows. There's an "invisible" 50-character line length limitation when editing `COMMIT_EDITMSG`. I say limitation, but really all it does is color the text red if you go beyond this limit:

[image]

How can I change this "hidden limit" so that the text will turn red at any line length I specify? For example, if I change this limit to 70, it should keep the text white until the 71st character, then turn red.

Here are a few things I've tried. First, I customized the `[git-commit]` language to set the column limit in VS Code `settings.json`:

```json
  "[git-commit]": {
    "editor.rulers": [70]
  },
```

This did not affect the behavior. I also tried explicitly setting some `git.*` settings. In particular:

```json
  "git.inputValidationLength": 70,
  "git.inputValidationSubjectLength": null
```

The docs for `git.inputValidationSubjectLength` state it uses the value of `git.inputValidationLength` if it is unset, but I did not see this change the behavior, either. I assume it's just for the GUI commit workflow.

I've Googled the heck out of this, I can't seem to find a solution. One may not exist, which is also an acceptable answer. At the end of the day I just don't want text color to change as I'm typing up to the longer line length limit I want.

Answer (score 5):

I use the [1Dark Raincoat (Bright Variant)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ginfuru.ginfuru-onedark-raincoat-theme) theme. It's delightful for nearly every language with which I've used it, but the 50+ character commit subject warning renders in a nearly unreadable color by default. I've dealt with this for years, but recently decided to dive into the problem and solve this annoyance once and for all.

First, to respond to some of what you've tried:

> I customized the `[git-commit]` language to set the column limit in VS Code `settings.json`:
>
> ```json
> "[git-commit]": {
>   "editor.rulers": [70]
> },
> ```

As you correctly noted, this does not affect this behavior. This is because the `editor.rulers` setting only affects the placement of vertical lines within editors, to indicate where that column lies for assistance with manual formatting by the user.

> I also tried explicitly setting some `git.*` settings. In particular:
>
> ```json
> "git.inputValidationLength": 70,  
> "git.inputValidationSubjectLength": null
> ```

You are correct that this only affects warnings displayed in the "Source Control" UI view, and so this also does not solve the problem.

I was able to find a solution by adding the following to my `settings.json`:

```json
// settings.json

"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
  "[Your Theme Here]": { // replace with your theme name, surrounded by [ ]
    "textMateRules": [
      {
        "scope": "invalid.deprecated.line-too-long.git-commit",
        "settings": { "foreground": "FOOBAR" } // replace with your desired color's HEX value
      },
      {
        "scope": "invalid.illegal.line-too-long.git-commit",
        "settings": { "foreground": "#FF0000" }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This solution modifies the colors used for two specific tokens exposed by the default (built-in) `git-commit` language syntax:

1. `invalid.deprecated.line-too-long.git-commit` affects the color of a commit subject line between 51 and 72 characters in length (inclusive)
2. `invalid.illegal.line-too-long.git-commit` affects the color of a commit subject line that is more than 72 characters in length

As written, this solution scopes the custom token colors to only the theme you specify on the second line of my example JSON. To apply these custom color settings to all themes, use `[*]` instead. In this particular case I believe it would be safe to do so, because the tokens appear to be highly specific to the `git-commit` syntax's subject lines, but I have not tested this extensively.

For some further reading:

1. Understanding [Tokenization](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide#tokenization) in syntax highlighting
2. Using the [Scope Inspector](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide#scope-inspector) to discover the tokens in use in a particular file/location

Comment: I realize that this does not allow you to change the 50 and 72 character limits, but those values are dictated by the built-in language syntax specification, [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/f0edba3e02b4ce5be481b39740e2b32d1fa979cb/extensions/git/syntaxes/git-commit.tmLanguage.json#L42-L49). There is no way to override these values using user- or workspace-level custom settings. I believe what I have outlined is the next-best thing.

Comment: So I could, for example, set both color values to white in order to somewhat visually disable the color change completely? I think this is also a more than acceptable solution, because I tend to rely on the vertical lines anyway to help me know when I've gone too far past the limit.

Comment: @void.pointer Yes you could do that. Personally I also set the lines to wrap automatically at 72 characters in my `[git-commit]`-specific user settings. The lines don’t break automatically, but it makes it so that I can just type out commit messages normally, and immediately see where to insert line breaks myself.

Comment: Check out the Rewrap extension. It does hard wrapping automatically and I love it. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stkb.rewrap

Comment: If I use this with [*] is it possible to reference other theme colors, instead of having to write hex codes directly?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is update the `git-commit.tmLanguage.json` at:

```
/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/git-base/syntaxes/git-commit.tmLanguage.json
```

Change this line to your desired length

[image]

After this, you should restart vscode and you will get the desired warning color in the `COMMIT_EDITMSG`